# Are Core 2 Quad CPUs interchangeable with Core 2 Duo?

Tags: central-processing-unit, multi-core

I have some aging Core 2 Duo systems in need of an upgrade.  The motherboard combinations are varied so I'm wondering, in a broad sense, are the Core 2 Duo procs interchangeable for Core 2 Quads or do I need to track down each individual motherboard model to check for compatability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on the chipset.  Figure out the chipset model and that should tell you what's supported and what's not.

From that, I looked at the wikipedia page for [Intel chipsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Core.2FCore_2_Mobile_Chipsets) and you can see that there are chipsets which support Core 2 Duo, but not the Core 2 Quad.  You'll have to figure out which chipsets are being used in your motherboards and see if it's one of those which does support both.

Comment: That being said, I can't find or think of a single board that supports c2q processors yet not c2d.